# Peskin & Schroeder's QFT book page 161

Tags: quantum-field-theory, dirac-matrices, trace

I am trouble with below derivation in Peskin & Schroeder's QFT book on page 161. At the bottom of this page,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\operatorname{tr}\left[\not p^{\prime} \gamma^{\mu} \not k \gamma^{\nu} \not p \gamma_{\nu} \not k \gamma_{\mu}\right] &=\operatorname{tr}\left[\left(-2 \not p^{\prime}\right) \not k(-2 \not p) \not k\right] \\
&=\operatorname{tr}\left[4 \not p^{\prime} \not k(2 p \cdot k- \not k \not p)\right] \\
&=8 p \cdot k \operatorname{tr}\left[\not p^{\prime}  \not k\right] \\
&=32(p \cdot k)\left(p^{\prime} \cdot k\right) .
\end{aligned}
$$
I am really troubled for the last step derivation, I thought the last coefficient should be 8, not 32, the reason is that
$$
\begin{aligned}
\operatorname{tr}[\not p^{\prime} \not k]&=\operatorname{tr}[p^{\prime}_{\mu}\gamma^{\mu}k_{\nu}\gamma^{\nu}]\\
&=\operatorname{tr}[p^{\prime}_{\mu}k_{\nu}(2g^{\mu \nu}-\gamma^{\nu}\gamma^{\mu})]\\
&=\operatorname{tr}[2p^{\prime}\cdot k-\not k \not p^{\prime}] \\
&=2p^{\prime}\cdot k - \operatorname{tr}[\not p^{\prime} \not k]
\end{aligned}
$$
so we can see that $$\operatorname{tr}[\not p^{\prime} \not k]=p^{\prime}\cdot k,$$ so in the last line, the coefficient should be still 8. Would you have some comment on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second calculation is wrong. Basically because you have to be a little bit more careful what you are taking the trace of! You use the anti-commutation relations for the Dirac matrices, which is commonly written down like
$$
\{\gamma^\mu, \gamma^\nu\} = 2 g^{\mu\nu},
$$
which is actually a bit sloppy. There is a $\mathbb I$ missing. You can easily see this observing that on the left there are matrices (which are entries of a 4-vector) and on the right there is only an entry of a tensor so there must be the identity.
Hence you end up with
$$
\text{tr}(\gamma^\mu \gamma^\nu) = \text{tr}(\{\gamma^\mu, \gamma^\nu\} - \gamma^\mu \gamma^\nu) = \text{tr}(2g^{\mu\nu}\mathbb I) -\text{tr}(\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu)
$$
$$
\implies\text{tr}(\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu) = \frac{2}{2} \text{tr}(g^{\mu\nu} \mathbb I)=4g^{\mu\nu}
$$
See also chapter 3.2 in "An Introduction to Quantum Field Theory" by M. Peskin and D.Schröder. (In my edition it is page 40)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation!